# Creating table with column name (having spaces in between)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table in which the column names have spaces.

like

```
create table IDE_Dump(
    Name varchar(255),
    Head Name varchar(255),
    Parent Account varchar (255)
);
```

The problem is to import bulk data from excel sheet to SQL Server 2008, whose headers are having the columns with spaces.

I have already tried ' ' or ` but its not working.

Comment: Although you *can* do this, don't.  Having to use escape characters to reference column names just makes queries harder to write and harder to read.  Use underscores or camelback casing.

Comment: Ya, I do that, but the thing is I am getting this Dump Excel Sheet, and I can not edit it. I have to use it as it is given. Anyway Thank You, Got what I need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add `[]` brackets to column name.

```
CREATE TABLE IDE_Dump
(
   Name VARCHAR(255),
   [Head Name] VARCHAR(255),
   [Parent Account] VARCHAR(255) 
);
```

Or you can use double quotes `""` as *jarlh* commented:

```
CREATE TABLE IDE_Dump
(
   Name VARCHAR(255),
   "Head Name" VARCHAR(255),
   "Parent Account" VARCHAR(255) 
);
```

Comment: Does the ANSI SQL way with "double quotes" work as well?

Comment: @jarlh Updated answer with your suggestion, if you are not against It.

Comment: First one worked for me, but "double quotes" i am not sure about it